# Deconvolution - two transfer functions applied to the same signal

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-algebra, convolution, toeplitz

I'm observing two timeseries, $\hat{h_1}$ and $\hat{h_2}$.
I believe that both are products of convolution of the same underlying signal $f$ with a two different transfer functions, $g_1$ and $g_2$, plus some noise, such that:

$\hat{h_1}=f*g_1+e_1$

$\hat{h_2}=f*g_2+e_2$

($e_1$ and $e_2$ are not white but they are unrelated to each other.)

One of the transfer functions, $g_1$, is known. The other transfer function, $g_2$ and the underlying signal $f$ are unknown. I wish to recover $g_2$.

I can first deconvolve $\hat{h_1}$ to obtain $\hat{f_1}$ and then substitute  $f$ in the second equation with it. However, I suspect that there's a principled way to approach this, that will correctly handle noise.. Note that I'm not really interested in estimating $f$ itself.

To add some spice, there are also missing values in the observed timeseries, so Time-Domain solutions might be better suited for the task (e.g. solving with Toeplitz matrices).

Comment: If you were to do it your way, how would you infer $g_2$? I assume by solving for its free variables? How exactly does $g_1$ look like? Note also that with you approach you are emposing the layout of the transfer function of $g_1$ on $g_2$. Are you certain these are of the same group of transfer functions?

Comment: Either in frequency-domain (division as deconvolution) or in time domain, indeed solving for the free variables.  g1 is essentially a known low-pass filter, I have no constraints about the shape of g2.

Comment: You  have no constraint on it but you need to decide for one or the other before you solve for the free variables. I doubt you can infer the function itself and the variables. I know, it is off-topic.

Comment: I think that the constraint I have in mind is that g2 is a FIR filter with certain maximal length n. Hence n free variables.

Comment: you have 3 known variables (h1, h2, g1), two equations, and either 2 unknowns (f, g2) or 4 unknowns (f, g2, e1, e2).  Algebra says that you should have more than one equation per unknown.  Right now your system is under-determined, and we need more equations to come to resolve it.

Comment: Following your scalar notation, if we don't consider e1 and e2, it's a two equations two variables system, which is not under-determined - it has a unique solution g2=h2g1/h1. Considering e1 and e2, the solution I'm looking for minimizes e1 and e2, hence it's still should be solvable. For example, not necessarily optimal solution can be achieved by first minimizing e1 to find f and then minimizing to find g2. The above question is about doing better than that.